# Restrict Over Exposed images

Tags: overexposure

[image]How to restrict overexposed images while I am using canon t1i and 18-55mm lens? Reception desk light is overexposed, you can see.

Comment: Can you clarify when to restrict, during take of photo, in post?

Answer (score 2):

This is typical situation of high dynamic range in interior photography. You can avoid such situation using for example HDR. Take several photos with bracketing and in post combine them. But speaking in generally you do not need to care so much about overexposure of the light source. It's understandable light source will be (almost) always overexposed.

The other way is to switch off this light, take photos and add some light in post. A bit of cheating but in some cases work much better.

Comment: @Tanveer, and do not forget to use tripod